# How iterate through WCF interface definition end points, operations and parameters

Tags: c#, wcf, interface, definition, endpoint

How do you get your WCF interface definition end points, operations and parameters programmatically to use in your code?

Answer (score 1):

This is a question I've wanted to know for a very long time and finally came across the solution I needed on Microsoft's MSDN website. Only wish I'd found it earlier. I will provide the answer and link below.

Use the System.ServiceModel.Description OperationDescription Class.

I get my ServiceHost like this in my code.

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri(OperationContext.Current.Host.BaseAddresses[0].AbsoluteUri);
ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyWebServiceClass), baseAddress);
```

The following code is from [Microsoft MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.operationdescription?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and does exactly what I need.

```
private void PrintDescription(ServiceHost sh)
{
    // Declare variables.
    int i, j, k, l, c;
    ServiceDescription servDesc = sh.Description;
    OperationDescription opDesc;
    ContractDescription contractDesc;
    MessageDescription methDesc;
    MessageBodyDescription mBodyDesc;
    MessagePartDescription partDesc;
    IServiceBehavior servBeh;
    ServiceEndpoint servEP;

    // Print the behaviors of the service.
    Console.WriteLine("Behaviors:");
    for (c = 0; c < servDesc.Behaviors.Count; c++)
    {
        servBeh = servDesc.Behaviors[c];
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", servBeh.ToString());                
    }

    // Print the endpoint descriptions of the service.
    Console.WriteLine("Endpoints");
    for (i = 0; i < servDesc.Endpoints.Count; i++)
    {
        // Print the endpoint names.
        servEP = servDesc.Endpoints[i];
        Console.WriteLine("\tName: {0}", servEP.Name);
        contractDesc = servEP.Contract;

        Console.WriteLine("\tOperations:");
        for (j = 0; j < contractDesc.Operations.Count; j++)
        {
            // Print the operation names.
            opDesc = servEP.Contract.Operations[j];
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t{0}", opDesc.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("\t\tActions:");
            for (k  = 0; k < opDesc.Messages.Count; k++)
            {
                // Print the message action. 
                methDesc = opDesc.Messages[k];
                Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tAction:{0}", methDesc.Action);

                // Check for the existence of a body, then the body description.
                mBodyDesc = methDesc.Body;
                if (mBodyDesc.Parts.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (l = 0; l < methDesc.Body.Parts.Count; l++)
                    {
                        partDesc = methDesc.Body.Parts[l];
                        Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t{0}",partDesc.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Please provide the actual links to the relevant source materials.

Comment: My pleasure. It's in the answer above the main code block.